# How to perform negative binomial regression on gut microbiome data with over dispersion?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, overdispersion

Thank you guys so much in advance!

I got a table, containing the information of gut microbial composition of different groups, that is, the count data of different bacteria in each sample of different groups. However, over-dispersion was observed.

To better compare the difference statistically of different groups, I thouhgt negative binomial regression should be performed, but i don't know much enough on the statistics, especailly the negative binomial regression. Does anybody know how to perform the regression and could help me to do so?
This is the microbial composition count table：

```
OTU_ID  D_1 D_10    D_11    D_12    D_13    D_14    D_15    D_16    D_17    D_2 D_3 D_4 D_5 D_6 D_7 D_8 D_9
k__Bacteria;__  31.0    37.0    156.0   11.0    133.0   137.0   178.0   109.0   50.0    9.0 27.0    15.0    1.0 3.0 8.0 3.0 35.0
k__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteria   43.0    31.0    18.0    60.0    115.0   82.0    0.0 46.0    286.0   65.0    23.0    44.0    7.0 23.0    8.0 31.0    11.0
k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidetes    4637.0  6871.0  3236.0  4887.0  3546.0  3636.0  2350.0  1945.0  1915.0  3632.0  4712.0  5240.0  5184.0  3675.0  5898.0  1526.0  2864.0
k__Bacteria;p__Cyanobacteria    23.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 10.0    7.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 81.0    451.0   32.0    216.0   0.0
k__Bacteria;p__Deferribacteres  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes   2723.0  1589.0  4836.0  3277.0  4669.0  4630.0  5588.0  6307.0  6207.0  3297.0  2830.0  2807.0  2743.0  3435.0  2012.0  2979.0  3574.0
k__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria   980.0   54.0    111.0   178.0   61.0    75.0    168.0   165.0   120.0   742.0   198.0   267.0   302.0   710.0   287.0   425.0   32.0
k__Bacteria;p__TM7  0.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 12.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
k__Bacteria;p__Tenericutes  42.0    21.0    288.0   205.0   106.0   78.0    362.0   62.0    56.0    97.0    246.0   215.0   89.0    345.0   66.0    58.0    159.0
k__Bacteria;p__Verrucomicrobia  167.0   43.0    1.0 24.0    6.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 12.0    804.0   610.0   58.0    239.0   0.0 335.0   3408.0  1971.0
```

this is the microbial composition abundance table:

```
Phylum  D_1 D_10    D_11    D_12    D_13    D_14    D_15    D_16    D_17    D_2 D_3 D_4 D_5 D_6 D_7 D_8 D_9
Bacteroidetes   0.536317372195235   0.79470275271802    0.374277122368725   0.565232477446218   0.410131852879944   0.420541290770298   0.271801989359241   0.224959518852649   0.221489706222531   0.420078649086283   0.54499190377053    0.606060606060606   0.599583622484386   0.425052047189452   0.682165163081194   0.176497802452001   0.331251445755263
Firmicutes  0.314943326393708   0.183784408975249   0.559333795975017   0.379019199629887   0.540018505667361   0.535507749248207   0.646310432569975   0.729470275271802   0.717904233171409   0.381332408049965   0.327318991441129   0.324658801758038   0.317256534813787   0.397293546148508   0.232708767059912   0.344552394170715   0.413370344668055
Verrucomicrobia 0.0193152903076567  0.0049733981031691  0.000115660421003932    0.00277585010409438 0.000693962526023595    0.000115660421003932    0   0   0.00138792505204719 0.0929909784871617  0.0705528568123988  0.00670830441822808 0.0276428406199399  0   0.0387462410363174  0.394170714781402   0.227966689798751
Proteobacteria  0.113347212583854   0.00624566273421235 0.0128383067314365  0.0205875549387 0.00705528568123988 0.00867453157529493 0.0194309507286607  0.0190839694656489  0.0138792505204719  0.0858200323849179  0.0229007633587786  0.03088133240805    0.0349294471431876  0.082118898912792   0.0331945408281286  0.0491556789266713  0.00370113347212584
Tenericutes 0.00485773768216516 0.00242886884108258 0.0333102012491325  0.0237103863058062  0.0122600046264168  0.00902151283830673 0.0418690724034236  0.00717094610224381 0.00647698357622022 0.0112190608373814  0.0284524635669674  0.0248669905158455  0.01029377746935    0.0399028452463567  0.00763358778625954 0.00670830441822808 0.0183900069396253
Low abundance   0.0112190608373814  0.00786490862826741 0.0201249132546842  0.00867453157529493 0.0298403886190146  0.0261392551468887  0.0205875549387 0.0193152903076567  0.0388619014573213  0.008558871154291   0.00578302105019662 0.00682396483923202 0.01029377746935    0.0556326625028915  0.00555170020818876 0.0289151052509831  0.00532037936618089
```

And this is the group information:

```
#SampleID   Group
D_1 30_degrees
D_2 30_degrees
D_3 30_degrees
D_4 30_degrees
D_5 30_degrees
D_6 30_degrees
D_7 30_degrees
D_8 30_degrees
D_9 22_degrees
D_10    22_degrees
D_11    22_degrees
D_12    22_degrees
D_13    22_degrees
D_14    4_degrees
D_15    4_degrees
D_16    4_degrees
D_17    4_degrees
```

If you need more information, don't hesitate to message me or leave a comment, please! Thank you so much in advance!

Best wishes,
Jiqiu

Comment: You seem to have [tag:compositional-data], not counts. Why do you think a negative binomial regression would be useful?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Hi, thank you so much! Indeed the data i uploaded is the compositional data derived from the count data. I have uploaded the original count data just now. Please have a look~ : )

Comment: Almost any statistical software that allows for generalized linear models (such as R) should have the capacity to perform a negative-binomial regression, in this case of bacterial counts as a function of microbe type and temperature. Is that your question? Note that software-specific questions are generally off-topic on this site, unless they bear on some more general statistical issue.